# Python Discord Bot cancel command

Tags: python, command, discord, bots

Hello I want to make a fun Discord bot with Python, I wrote a spam command. Now I want to make a new command that stop this.

Here is the command:

```
@commands.command()
async def spam(self,ctx, msg="hi", *, amount=1):
    for i in range(0, amount):
            await ctx.send(msg)
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an easy solution to this. Outside of the function `spam`, declare a `bool` variable with any name (i.e. `stop`), and instantiate that value to `False`. Inside the spam function. Inside the spam function, declare `global stop` and re-instantiate `stop` to `False`. Then just use a while loop to know when to stop, and create another command that will update the stop value to `True` ending the spam command.

The solution would look like the following:

```py
stop = False

@commands.command()
async def spam(self, ctx, msg='hi', *, amount=1):
    global stop
    stop = False
    i = 0
    while not stop and i < amount:
        await ctx.send(msg)
        i += 1

@commands.command()
async def stop(self, ctx):
    global stop
    stop = True
```

From here, you can add any other logic necessary regarding your command.

It is also recommended to sleep the thread in between messages as to not overload your server. This can be done by importing the `time` module and injecting the line `time.sleep(1)` after the line `await ctx.send(msg)`.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: No problem! Have fun!